# Can't connect to postgres on ubuntu

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, dbeaver

I have a ubuntu 20 on dreamcompute (which is cloud computing).

I create a user and a database. Here is the list of database and users (for some reason, I can't see database under a `matt` username).

I went into:
`nano /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf` &
`nano /etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf` and did the whole `'*'` and `'0.0.0.0/0'`

```
postgres=# \l
                              List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
 strapi    | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |         |         | hossein=CTc/postgres
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

as you can see you can't see `Superuser` and database `strapi` under the `matt` username.

```
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 matt      |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 ubuntu    |                                                            | {}
```

I'm using my dream compute's `ip address` as my host and use my database and user and password but get error message: `connection attempt time out`.

[image]

Could someone *please* give me a pointer on why this is happening? I have been working onthis for 2 weeks now and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried `ALTER ROLE matt WITH LOGIN;`?

Comment: @richyen I'm new to this but that changes it to `matt` being the default login account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as ex4 mentioned above I needed to reachout to the company that I was renting my cloud computer from but I still could not connect to the database.

The way I went around it is that you can `ssh` into your database and then connect to your database as a `localhost` since you are `ssh` into your cloud computer.

In DBeaver you have a `ssh` tab and you can connect and then you got back to your `postgres` tab and fill the `localhost`, `user`, `database name`, and `user password` area and simply click `connect`.

Sadly this took weeks to come to this :/

Comment: You could do simple SSH tunneling like `ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432'. But SSH tunneling isn't really a solution for your problem, if you want to go production with it.

Answer (score 1):

Error message is `connection time out`. That usually means that the port is blocked by a firewall. Check your cloud provider firewall settings and `iptables`in your Linux box in case you have installed it.

If there was problem with permissions, the error message would be something else.